# Setup custom request context with flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a complex service that runs flask queries asynchronously. So the flask app accepts requests and submits them to a queue and returns a handle to the caller. Then an async service picks up these requests and runs them and then submits the response to a data-store. The caller would continuously poll the flask endpoint to check if the data is available. Currently, this asynchronous feature is only available for a single flask endpoint. But I want to extend this to multiple flask endpoints. As such, I am putting in the code that submits the request to the queue in a python decorator. So that this decorator can be applied to any flask endpoint and then it would support this asynchronous feature.

But to achieve this seamlessly, I have the need to setup a custom request context for flask. This is because the flask endpoints use request.args, request.json, jsonify from flask. And the async service just calls the functions associated with the flask endpoints.

I tried using app.test_request_context() but this doesn't allow me to assign to request.json.

```
with app.test_request_context() as req:
    req.request.json = json.dump(args)
```

The above doesn't work and throws the below error

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you need a custom request context. Have you tried using celery with Flask? There are a lot of patterns that will probably work well for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

```
builder = EnvironBuilder(path='/',
                         query_string=urllib.urlencode(query_options), method='POST', data=json.dumps(post_payload),
                                     content_type="application/json")
env = builder.get_environ()

with app.request_context(env):
    func_to_call(*args, **kwargs)
```